# Cannot execute PHP online server

Tags: php, server

I want to execute a PHP server on my site. IP address of the site is 31.170.161.16.
The socket is not creating when i execute this code. Is this the address used for $host or any other? Please help.

```
<?php
    // set ip and port
    $host = "31.170.161.16";
    $port = 4096;

    // don't timeout!
    set_time_limit(0);

    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // bind socket to port
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);

    // start listening for connections
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3);

    // accept incoming connections
    // spawn another socket to handle communication
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

    // read client input
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

    // clean up input string
    $input = trim($input);
    echo "Client Message : ".$input."<br />";

    // reverse client input and send back
    $output = strrev($input) ."<br />";
    socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");

    // close sockets
    socket_close($spawn);
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the host company looks like a free hosting company. just because its free that doesn't mean all the php features will be available to you. I recommend signing up with a reputable company instead such as digitalocean.com